how to implement startActivityForResult and get a json response from another app
EDIT: apologies seems this proyect uses an old version of android, or non updated repositories. i cant update them sadly. so ActivityResultContract is not present. but i do have startActivityForResult.
im trying to use ActivityResultContract to obtain the response from another app and use it on mine, but so far i can only reach the app but not obtain any response back.
so the comunication reaches. but never returns (im super new on java and android. i was a junion c# developer q.q)
this is the code im using to comunicate
    @PluginMethod
    public void openApp(PluginCall call) {
        savedCall = call;
        String operation = call.getString("operation");
        String id = call.getString("id");
        String amount = call.getString("amount");
        String account = call.getString("account");
        String app_id = call.getString("app_id");
        String LogName = "inicio";
        TaLogger.saveLog(LogName, "");
        TaLogger.saveLog(LogName, " variables " + operation + " " + id + " " + amount + " " + account + " " + app_id);

        Intent intent = new Intent("My intent, removed. safety first!");
        intent.putExtra("operation", operation);
        intent.putExtra("id", id);
        intent.putExtra("amount", amount);
        intent.putExtra("account", account);
        intent.putExtra("app_id", app_id);

        BridgeActivity activity = (BridgeActivity) this.getActivity();
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 1118);
    }


and on the app im using this
const fnTestPlugin = async () => {
  try {
    TaSleep(5000)
    const result = await SunmiPOSPlugin.realizarCompra({
      operation: '200',
      id: ' my id number',
      amount: '1,00',
      account: '2',
      app_id: 'hidden'
    });

    console.log('Result:', result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  }
};

 fnTestPlugin();

to test it,
as it stands. like i said, i reach the app. the app does respond. but i never get any response on my side.
tried a couple of ways to do. but the other one crashed the app. cuz i was trying to invoque while... resume? i realy dont understand android too much
the responses i need to log are somethign along this lines
RESPONSE ON getsEFTSECInfo LIB----> {"code":"99","EFTSEC":[],"DUKPT":[]}
RESPONSE ON getsEFTSECInfo LIB----> {"code":"00","EFTSEC":[],"DUKPT":[]}

FMX: Dummy: {"message":{"bankName":"hidden","bankRif":"hidden","commerceName1":"TEST P2mini","commerceAddress":"hidden, hidden","commerceRif":"1234","affiliate":"hidden","msgCompromiso":"test","tipo_tarjeta":"hidden","terminal":"hidden","batch":"000003","cardNumber":"hidden","date":"hidden","time":"07:59:10 PM","appIdMIR":"hidden","codigo_autorizacion":"hidden","reference":"hidden","trace":"000435","currency":"Bs.","amount":"1,00","commitmentMsg":"","code":"00"}}


Well, how does the receiving app set the result (setResult) and how are you trying to handle it (onActivityResult)?
